# How to overwrite a file without closing it

Tags: c++, file-io

There have been numerous questions about how to write to a file without overwriting it.

But this time I need to know how to open a file and then write a value comprising few characters in it. the value is very short but this process of replacing the file content with an updated value can occur a billion times.

So here is the question again: Is there a way to write to such a file by opening it once and not closing it before overwriting the content many times?

perhaps if I told you why i need this, it would help you give me a better solution.
I need to write the current time of a simulator to a file to be read and used by another simulator (for synchronization purposes)

and a psudo code:

```
int main() {

    int i = 0;
 std::ofstream myWriteFile;
 ostringstream out;
 myWriteFile.open("text.txt");

 while (i < 4) {    
     out.str("");
     out << currentTime();
    myWriteFile << out.str() << std::endl;
    i++;
 }

myWriteFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position the "put" pointer to the beginning of the file before writing to it using [std::ostream::seekp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/):

```
myWriteFile.seekp(0);
```

The "put" pointer specifies the position in which you want to write in the file. It is automatically incremented when you write something, which is why writing continuously to the file results in the data being appended to the end of the previously written data.

Comment: thanks for the reply. suppose if write XXXXX to the file and using seekp get back to the beginning of the file and write YYY. The output will be YYYXX while i need it to be just YYY. right? I can delete the contents before writing but is there a better way? thanks

Comment: You can't truncate an open file. You still to reopen it if you want that. However, you can write a terminating character in it, and the other simulator then reads only up to that character. A `\n` for example would work, in which case you only consider the first line as being important.

Comment: yes. I guess that is a good way. thanks (i have another question which I will just bring it up in another post)